# Laptop keyboard not working after boot (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: grub2, keyboard, 18.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my chromebook (Lenovo N22) after changing the original BIOS to SeaBIOS, but now my in-built keyboard stops working as soon as Ubuntu boots (I can still use the in-built keyboard in the BIOS). An external keyboard works perfectly. I've tried adding i8042 parameters (dumbkbd, nopnp, nomux, etc) to the /etc/default/grub file & reinstalling both xserver-xorg-input-all and Ubuntu itself, none of which worked. If anyone could help, it would be greatly appreciated.

PS: My trackpad & my power button (power off menu opens up when I press it) still work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My chromebook was using SeaBIOS as a BIOS in RW_LEGACY. I just recently learned that I could install SeaBIOS in Full ROM (so I did) and now my keyboard works perfectly. I hope that I could help someone in the future :)